# DBUnit bytea insert

Tags: java, spring, spring-security-oauth2, dbunit, spring-test-dbunit

I'm using Spring Oauth and I'm trying to insert test data into oauth_client_token table (client side Spring Oauth 2). When I look at the bytecode for Spring Oauth's `JdbcClientTokenService.saveAccessToken`, I'm seeing this:

```
 jdbcTemplate.update(
            insertAccessTokenSql,
            new Object[] { accessToken.getValue(), new SqlLobValue(SerializationUtils.serialize(accessToken)),
                    keyGenerator.extractKey(resource, authentication), name,
                    resource.getClientId() }, new int[] { Types.VARCHAR, Types.BLOB, Types.VARCHAR, Types.VARCHAR,
                    Types.VARCHAR });
```

What I'm concern about is this section `new SqlLobValue(SerializationUtils.serialize(accessToken))` which is generating **bytes** of an object. I wanted a way for DBUnit to insert all this data during my integration test. What I did before was to generate a base64 byte string of some random string and let DBUnit insert it. However, when the `JdbcClientTokenService.getAccessToken` is called, which calls SerializationUtils.deserialize on the byte, I get incorrect header exception. I believe this happen because, base64 is not generating the same output as SerializationUtils.serialize. Let me know if there's a way for me to use DBUnit to insert the correct data.

Thanks